# Bounding Probability Distribution

Tags: probability

I have the following problem. Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with image $[0, b]$ for some finite $b>0$. So we have finite moments, $\mathbb{E}[X^n]$. I am hoping to say something about the possible size of $b$ given that I know finitely many moments of $X$, say the first $N$ moments, along with estimates $$f_n\leq \mathbb{E}[X^n]\leq g_n$$ for some sequences $f_n , g_n$. So maybe, one can try and show something like $$\mathbb{P}[X>C+\mbox{something small}]\leq \mbox{something small}.$$ This would be wonderful.

Comment: Or perhaps show that $\mathbb{P}[X<C]$ is very close to $1$ for some $C$.

Comment: Theres a whole field of these sort of ideas called concentration inequalities (the simplest being derived from Markov/Chebyshev inequalities).